# Creating Spatial Index for GeoPackage using QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-index, geopackage

Working in QGIS 2.18.14 standalone on Windows, is there a way to create a Spatial Index for GeoPackage (gpkg) layers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible through the QGIS UI at the moment. Read the GDAL GeoPackage vector manual http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html and use ogrinfo.

```
ogrinfo -SQL "SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('table_name', 'geom_column_name')" geopackage.gpkg
```

Comment: I think you need "SELECT Create..." to make it work

Answer (score 20):

It's possible in QGIS 3. You can click "Create Spatial index" from the Layer Properties Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Does this option also enable spatial index auto updates?

Answer (score 1):

There's also the processing tool: Create spatial index:

> Creates an index to speed up access to the features in a layer based
> on their spatial location. Support for spatial index creation is
> dependent on the layer's data provider.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess this processing tool has been around since QGIS 2.16, which worked only for shapefiles at the time of the question.