# Identifying neighbouring polygons but field calculator preview and output are different

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, proximity, aggregate

I'm really struggling trying to create a field which lists the neighbouring cells of my grid. I have a grid of 814 cells, and for most cells (i.e. the ones which are fully surrounded) there are eight neighbouring cells.

In the field calculator, I am setting the field type to string, and the field length to a number way higher than needed. The layer is called "Clip" and the output I want is a list of the `"id"` numbers which is a field in itself.

The preview of this code is correct. For most cells, the output is eight. But when I click <kbd>Ok</kbd>, the output in the new field is `NULL`. I've tried changing the filter to `touches()` and I've tried adding a buffer around the `geometry(@parent)` bit.

The code I'm using is...

```
aggregate(
    layer:= 'clip',
    aggregate:= 'concatenate',
    expression:= to_string("id"),
    concatenator:= ', ',
    filter:= intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```

Comment: I suggest to check [@Babel's answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel?tab=answers), i think once he answered the same question

Comment: Have you tried to convert this aggregate to string with `array_to_string(your_current_code)` ?

Comment: if it is not mandatory to work with `aggregate(...)` , one can use this expression: `array_to_string(array_sort(overlay_touches(@layer, "id")))`

Comment: The array_to_string code is definitely a step in the right direction thank you!!! I opened the grid in a new QGIS project, so it didn't have all the other things going on around it. And I tried this code. I got some really good outputs, but mostly I have only 6 or 7 of the 8 neighbouring cells. Is there a way of indicating all cells which are within a given radius?

Comment: do a `buffer` function with your `$geometry`. Beware of geographic CRS like WGS84, buffer function is better with cartesian and projected coordinate systems.

Comment: The function you are using outputs a string, but if you try to use it in a defined numeric field you will always get NULL. Then, try to create a new field and define it as a string.

Comment: using virtual layers gives you more flexibility.  Similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318205/7849

Comment: So the code which worked was array_to_string(array_sort(overlay_touches(@layer, "id"))). I'm not sure how to add a buffer to this. I'm working in WGS84.
I did read the other post on SQL, but I don't have it downloaded and have no knowledge of how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'grid_test'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

There is a method that may help you to achieve the desired output by means of the Field Calculator.

### 1. [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects)

```
array_to_string(array_sort(overlay_intersects(@layer, "id")))
```

### 2. [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate)

As was mentioned by @J.Monticolo in his comment, one can use a small buffer around `$geometry`.

```
aggregate(
    layer:=@layer,
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:=to_string("id"),
    concatenator:=',',
    filter:=intersects(buffer($geometry, 0.2), geometry(@parent))
        and geom_to_wkt($geometry) != geom_to_wkt(geometry(@parent))
    )
```

The output shall look as following:

*Output:*
[image: result1]